# What do "the kitchen sink" and "farm" here mean?

Tags: meaning, phrase-meaning, idioms

I get stuck in understanding the way the author phrases his thoughts in [this blog](https://medium.com/intuitionmachine/should-deep-learning-use-complex-numbers-edbd3aac3fb8):

> We’ve already bet the kitchen sink on linear algebra and differential
>   functions, we might as well just go all in and bet the farm on complex
>   analysis.

I can grasp the point of the sentence but am not familiar with the analogy. I conjecture he means mainly that we can just take a plunge into unknown waters(complex analysis) since we already have benefited from the less powerful linear algebra and differential functions just for real numbers(real analysis).

Am I wrong? And how can I comprehend the "bet the kitchen sink on sth" and "bet the farm on sth else"?

Answer (score 2):

"The kitchen sink" metaphorically means "everything" -- actually, it's a truncation of "everything but the kitchen sink" (as in "He puts everything but the kitchen sink in his famous stew").

It's not really idiomatic to say "bet the kitchen sink".  The idea of "everything but the kitchen sink" is you have some ridiculous collection of odds-and-ends, not anything of great value.

"Bet the farm" means to bet essentially everything you have.  I imagine for the average small farmer, the farm does represent his only asset.

Answer (score 0):

Let me add to [@Malvolio's answer](https://ell.stackexchange.com/a/169317)

According to Cambridge Dictionary

[**everything but/except the kitchen sink**](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/es/diccionario/ingles/everything-but-except-the-kitchen-sink)

> a much larger number of things than is necessary

This [site](https://www.knowyourphrase.com/everything-but-the-kitchen-sink) (knowyourphrase.com) offers a lightly different interpretation

> Including **nearly** everything possible

Your phrase doesn't use this exact idiom. If you have already bet **nearly everything** – all but the kitchen sink – there is not much difference with betting **everything** – the whole farm. I think that **the kitchen sink** in your context represents only a part of your "money" and the **farm** is the all-in, all you can bet.